# Sinatra can't convert Symbol into Integer when making MongoDB query

Tags: ruby, mongodb, sinatra, typeerror

This is a sort of followup to my other MongoDB question about the torrent indexer.

I'm making an open source torrent indexer (like a mini TPB, in essence), and offer both SQLite and MongoDB for backend, currently.

However, I'm having trouble with the MongoDB part of it. In Sinatra, I get [image: this error] when trying to upload a torrent, or search for one.

In uploading, one needs to tag the torrent — and it fails here. The code for adding tags is as follows:

```
def add_tag(tag)
  if $sqlite
    unless tag_exists? tag
      $db.execute("insert into #{$tag_table} values ( ? )", tag)
    end
    id = $db.execute("select oid from #{$tag_table} where tag = ?", tag)
    return id[0]
  elsif $mongo
    unless tag_exists? tag
      $tag.insert({:tag => tag})
    end
    return $tag.find({:tag => tag})[:_id] #this is the line it presumably crashes on
  end
end
```

It reaches line 105 (noted above), and then fails. What's going on? Also, as an FYI this might turn into a few other questions as solutions come in.

Thanks!

EDIT

So instead of returning the tag result with `[:_id]`, I changed the block inside the elsif to:

```
id = $tag.find({:tag => tag})
puts id.inspect
return id
```

and still get an error. You can see a demo at http://torrent.hypeno.de and the source at [http://github.com/tekknolagi/indexer/](http://github.com/tekknolagi/indexer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that you are doing an `insert()`, the easiest way to get the id is:

```
 id = $tag.insert({:tag => tag})
```

`id` will be a [BSON::ObjectId](http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/BSON/ObjectId.html), so you can use appropriate methods depending on the return value you want:

```
 return id         #  BSON::ObjectId('5017cace1d5710170b000001')
 return id.to_s    # "5017cace1d5710170b000001"
```

In your original question you are trying to use the [Collection.find()](http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/Mongo/Collection.html#find-instance_method) method.  This  returns a [Mongo::Cursor](http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/Mongo/Cursor.html), but you are trying to reference the cursor as a document.  You need to iterate over the cursor using `each` or `next`, eg:

```
 cursor = $tag.find_one({:tag => tag})
 return cursor.next['_id'];
```

If you want a single document, you should be using [Collection.find_one()](http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/Mongo/Collection.html#find_one-instance_method).

For example, you can find and return the _id using:

```
 return $tag.find_one({:tag => tag})['_id']
```

Comment: Can I change a Mongo::Cursor into an iterable array?

Comment: @tekknolagi: Mongo::Cursor is already an iterator .. so you can use [each](http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/Mongo/Cursor.html#each-instance_method) or [next](http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/Mongo/Cursor.html#next-instance_method) to fetch documents.  For example: `$tag.find({:tag => tag}).each do |doc| ... end`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is `[:_id]`. I dont know much about Mongo but `` `$tag.find({:tag => tag}) `` is probably retutning an array and passing a symbol to the [] array operator is not defined.

Comment: Okay, now I have: `id = $tag.find({:tag => tag}); puts id.inspect; return id` but get the same error

Comment: It cant be the exact same error. The location was ```[]``` what does it say now?

Comment: What does the puts say? Try printing the class as well.

Comment: The `puts` doesn't end up putting anything